# How do I allocate memory for ZIP struct?

Tags: c++, winapi, zip

I found a [ZIP library](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7530/Zip-Utils-Clean-Elegant-Simple-Cplusplus-Win) that I want to re-write with WinAPI calls.
I have almost done it, but I can't allocate memory for a `TState` structure.

`state = new TState();` works fine!

`state = (TState*)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, sizeof(TState));` breaks archives!

If I change `HeapAlloc()` to `malloc()`, nothing changes!

So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Makes no sense that you can't call `new`.

Comment: If you want to use a zip library in an environment in which you are not allowed to use operator `new`, then it would probably be easier to look for a C library instead of a C++ library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TState` contains some non-trivial members (namely: `TTreeState ts` and `TDeflateState ds`) that have their own constructors which are called properly by `new`, but which are not called by `malloc()`/`HealAlloc()`. As such, you would need to use [`placement-new`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Placement_new) to properly construct a `TState` object inside of your allocated memory, eg:

```
buffer = HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, sizeof(TState)); // or malloc()
state = new(buffer) TState;
...
state->~TState();
HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, buffer); // or free()
```

Otherwise, you will have to re-write `TTreeState` and `TDeflateState` to make them into trivial types (ie, remove their constructors).  You will just have to initialize their data members manually after you have allocated each `TState` instance.

Comment: I need to initialize it properly via HeapAlloc(), I can't use CRT functions laboratory work...

Comment: See the update I just posted. You can't initalize it with `HeapAlloc()` alone. You can't avoid the work that the constructors are doing. But you can move the logic around.

Comment: Couldn't you just override `operator new` and `operator delete`, so they use `HeapAlloc()` and `HeapFree()` respectively?